# AS3 error- when trying to hit test object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

I am trying to test for the collision of two objects. Both are on the display list. They are movie clips, each containing a hit box. One is called hitboxx, and the other is called hits. However, when I test the following code:

```
if (character2.hitboxx.hitTestObject(Spike1.hits)||character2.hitboxx.hitTestObject(Spike2.hits)||character2.hitboxx.hitTestObject(Spike3.hits))
{
    currLives--;
}
```

I get this error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at SpikeJungle_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[SpikeJungle_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:126]

Comment: There are not two but four objects. hitboxx, Spike1, Spike2, Spike3.

Comment: In your debugger, you can find which variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

it's difficult to say anything on the code. The code seems correct. May be you forget to add variable name or something. Or try to check one movie clip at  a time. means try to remove the other condition in and check with one and see whether it's working. And also in Publish Settings >> Advanced >> permit Debugging check this option and compile again and you will get more about the errors.

Comment: I now have this information `TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
 at SpikeJungle_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[SpikeJungle_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:159]` and I dont know how to fix that

Comment: The object you specified in the hittestobject is null. That's the error says. Did you tried one object at a time? if (character2.hitboxx.hitTestObject(Spike1.hits)) like this. and post the result here.